# Passing Authenticated User object to object constructor in Laravel, says none is given

Tags: php, oop, laravel, constructor, laravel-5

I am having a problem i cannot wrap my head around in laravel.

I am trying to created a new instance of an object with a User object specified in the constructor. I am passing the Auth::user() to it but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
public function requestStudentProject($id)
{       

    $student_request = new StudentRequest(Auth::user());
    $student_request->requestProject($id);
}
```

and here is a snippet of my class:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\User;

class StudentRequest extends Model{

protected $table = 'student_project_requests';

protected $user;

public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user=$user;
}
```

this gives me an error:

`Argument 1 passed to App\StudentRequest::__construct() must be an instance of App\User, none given, called in /home/vagrant/w3students/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 986 and defined`

Can anyone help? i have been trying to wrap my head around this for hours. Thanks!

Comment: overriding a model like this can be tricky, i prefer to remove the `public function __construct(..)` and change the `new StudentRequest(Auth::user())` to `new StudentRequest(Auth::user()->getAttributes())` -  or `StudentRequest::create(Auth::user()->getAttributes())` - instead. as the model actually have their own [`__construct(..)`](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method___construct). **ps** this assuming you had identical field on StudentRequest and you user table.

Comment: Auth::user() returns user object as long as you're authenticated. Make sure this is the case.

Comment: Yes, probably you are not authenticated.